# Spring security is not rendering custom login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I just began to learn spring security without using spring boot. I am trying to render my own custom login page. Controller method with requestmapping "/login" has been called several times but spring is not rendering login.jsp page.

This is my root configuration classes :

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.repository")
@Import(SecurityConfiguration.class)
public class AppConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    
    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.example.model");
        
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
    
    public Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect");
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean(name = "mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector") 
    public HandlerMappingIntrospector mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector() { 
        return new HandlerMappingIntrospector(); 
    }
}
```

This one is dispatcher context configuration class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.controller"})
public class DispatcherServletConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

And here is my security configuration class :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.example.service")
public class SecurityConfiguration{
    
    @Resource
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        builder.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        return builder.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/").authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll();

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

WebApplicationInitializer is :

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
  
  
  @Override 
  public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
  
      //Declaring root context 
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);
      
      //Manage the life cycle of root application context 
      container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
      
      //Creating dispatcher servlet's application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherServletConfig.class);
      
      
      //Register and Map dispatcher servlet 
      ServletRegistration.Dynamic
      dispatcherServlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext)); 
      dispatcherServlet.addMapping("/");
      dispatcherServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      
      
  }
  
}
```

and controller class is :

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String indexPage() {
        return "index";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        System.out.println("have been called");
        return "login";
    }
}
```

While trying to access the url i got the following error on browser
[image]

I enabled the security debug and result is as follows (printed out more than 20 times on console).

```
cookie: JSESSIONID=9B485D0205797A978E6A25A54DBBAC88


Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]


************************************************************


2023-03-13T20:24:01.020+09:00  INFO 13976 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/login':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@4ff9b4c7

servletPath:/login
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
cache-control: max-age=0
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/110.0.1587.69
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
sec-fetch-site: none
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-user: ?1
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="110", "Not A(Brand";v="24", "Microsoft Edge";v="110"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: ja,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7
cookie: JSESSIONID=9B485D0205797A978E6A25A54DBBAC88


Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]


************************************************************


2023-03-13T20:24:01.029+09:00  INFO 13976 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] Spring Security Debugger                 : 

************************************************************

Request received for GET '/login':

org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@388d5e7e

servletPath:/login
pathInfo:null
headers: 
host: localhost:8080
connection: keep-alive
cache-control: max-age=0
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/110.0.1587.69
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
sec-fetch-site: none
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-user: ?1
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="110", "Not A(Brand";v="24", "Microsoft Edge";v="110"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: ja,en;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.7
cookie: JSESSIONID=9B485D0205797A978E6A25A54DBBAC88


Security filter chain: [
  DisableEncodeUrlFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextHolderFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  AuthorizationFilter
]
```

Comment: please enable spring security `DEBUG` logs and post them here so that we actually see what is going on.

Comment: @Toerktumlare sorry for being late to reply. I enabled debug and edited my question.

Comment: This is not the spring security debug logs, please look up on how to enable spring security debug logs. Also a large portion of the logs are missing, the startup logs etc.

Comment: @Rohit facing the same issue here. were you able to solve this by your own?

Comment: @HasankaSapumal play with request matcher for a while and you would get idea what’s wrong. And don’t forget to allow access to your JavaScript, css, html or jsp resources.

Comment: @rohith turned out spring 6 security needs .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD).permitAll() to be added in our config